# Should we take [pictures] and [images] out of the picture?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

There's [images](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/images) tag, which has as description:

> Questions about opening / editing / saving images using image-editing applications.

And then there's [pictures](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/pictures) with no description.

IMHO:

1. As far as image-editing goes, we already have tags for [image-processing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/image-processing) and for specific applications like [imagemagick](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/imagemagick) and [gimp](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/gimp)
2. Opening and finding images on disk - that can easily fall under [files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/files) or [find](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/find).

So what do you think, community? Do we need these tags?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[images](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/images) is a poor tag name, not only because it does not define any specific task or software, but also because it has more than one distinct meaning, especially in our scope. A brief survey shows that this tag is being used for questions about images that are not pictures of stuff, for example

- [Mount single partition from image of entire disk (device)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69363/mount-single-partition-from-image-of-entire-disk-device)
- [What software can be used to create a restorable drive image?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7576/what-software-can-be-used-to-create-a-restorable-drive-image)
- [Why aren't old linux-images removed when installing new kernel updates?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100733/why-arent-old-linux-images-removed-when-installing-new-kernel-updates)

It seems to me that those three posts (there are more examples similar to each of them) do not benefit from an [image](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/image) tag and the "image" aspects of them are sufficiently defined by tags like [backup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/backup) and [kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/kernel). We also have a tag [disk-image](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/disk-image) which would be applicable to the first two.

There are currently 476 posts with this tag, which means a long process to remove it by editing. The majority of the questions are about image processing or specific software as you suggested, and some can simply be tagged [software-recommendations](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/software-recommendations), but some of them are about converting non-images to images (there is a tag [convert](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/convert) but that is probably at least as problematic as [images](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/images)), or about viewing or saving or identifying or organising images. [image-processing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/image-processing) may not be appropriate for all of them. There is a tag [photo-management](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/photo-management) which may be more suitable for some. Careful work is needed to apply specific software tags where appropriate.

[pictures](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/pictures) is probably less ambiguous, but similarly unnecessary and vague in failing to define a specific task or program.

Both should be carefully removed, imho.

---

We also have a tag [photo](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/photo) which doesn't seem useful...

Comment: Agreed. IMHO the edge cases you mention can be covered by other tags. The first 2 appear to be good candidates for [tag:disk-image] while the third one looks like it's already tagged [tag:kernel] and doesn't need the [tag:images] at all. I've edited them accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

No we don’t, let’s retag the questions according to your suggestions and remove both [images](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/images) and [pictures](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/pictures).

*Feel free to edit this answer to add your reasons why we should delete these tags.*